# How do I get intellij's clojure console to load the dependencies defined in leiningen?

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, leiningen

I've installed the "la Clojure" and "leiningen" plugins. I've created a clojure project and added the lib/ folder as a library in my project. With this done the editor knows about the libraries and if I 'run' a clojure file it successfully loads the dependencies, but if I start a console within intellij it doesn't load the dependencies. How do I get the console to load them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I open the project settings, add lib and lib/dev as JAR directories (IntelliJ scans them for changes and updates the classpath automatically). This works with the Clojure console.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
lein pom
```

to generate pom.xml if it does not already exists and let idea to use maven to track the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I created a clojure file that `require`s all of my source files. then from the repl screen I `(load "start-repl.clj")`. It's not a really good solution because of the manual steps but it gets me hacking...

Comment: I'll end up doing something like this if there isn't a good way

Comment: La Clojure is developing nicely to perhaps it will just be until something better comes along